# Explode/foreach not working to record multiple values from checkbox into multiple rows in database

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, explode

I'm currently working on a online youth mentorship portal which requires mentors and mentees to sign up.
The mentor sign up form has a checkbox area where they click on the categories they wish to mentor in. They can click on as many as they want. My problems are as follows:

1) Despite noting it as an array and using implode while using $_POST and explode and foreach while inserting into the database, i only seem to get the first option chosen in the checkbox being recorded in the database. Please kindly help me out with this.

2) i have 3 tables for this particular script; Mentor, Category and Logged Category to record the data for normalization purposes. On top of the problem number (1), the mentor table seems to be getting 3 replicated row entries per sign up. What might be the issue?

Here is an excerpt from the form:

```html
<form id="form1" name="form1" action="registration.php" method=POST>

<label for="name">Full name:</label>
<input type="text" id="name" name="name">
          
<label for="mail">Email:</label>
<input type="email" id="mail" name="email">
          
<label for="password">Password:</label>
<input type="password" id="password" name="pass">
          
<label>Gender:</label>
<input type="radio" id="m" value="m" name="gender"><label for="male" class="light">Male</label><br>
<input type="radio" id="f" value="f" name="gender"><label for="female" class="light">Female</label>

<label for="bio">Biography:</label>
<textarea id="bio" name="bio"></textarea>
        
<label>Category to Mentor in:</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="ICT" value="1" name="catID[]">         
<label class="light" for="ICT">ICT</label><br>

<input type="checkbox" id="Music" value="2" name="catID[]">
<label class="light" for="Music">Music</label><br>

<input type="checkbox" id="Politics" value="3" name="catID[]">
<label class="light" for="Politics">Politics</label><br>

<input type="checkbox" id="Entrepreneurship" value="4" name="catID[]">
<label class="light" for="Entrepreneurship">Entrepreneurship</label><br>

<input type="checkbox" id="Sports" value="5" name="catID[]">
<label class="light" for="Sports">Sports</label><br>

<input type="checkbox" id="Religious" value="6" name="catID[]">
<label class="light" for="Religious">Religious</label><br>

<input type="checkbox" id="Agriculture" value="7" name="catID[]">
<label class="light" for="Agriculture">Agriculture</label><br>

<input type="checkbox" id="Finance" value="8" name="catID[]">
<label class="light" for="Finance">Finance & Banking</label><br>

<input type="checkbox" id="Leadership" value="9" name="catID[]">
<label class="light" for="Leadership">Leadership</label><br>

<input type="checkbox" id="Science" value="10" name="catID[]">
<label class="light" for="Science">Science</label><br>

<input type="checkbox" id="Fashion" value="11" name="catID[]">
<label class="light" for="Fashion">Fashion/Beauty</label><br>

<input type="checkbox" id="Medical" value="12" name="catID[]">
<label class="light" for="Medical">Medical</label><br>
          

<input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit" value="Sign Up">
</form>
```

This is my registration.php

```
<?php

$a = $_POST['name'];
$b = $_POST['email'];
$c = $_POST['pass'];
$d = $_POST['gender'];
$e = $_POST['bio'];
$fimp= implode(', ', $_POST['catID']);
if($a && $b && $c && $d && $e && $fimp) {

    if ( filter_var(($_POST["email"]), FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)  == TRUE) {
        $con=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','');
        if(!$con) {
            die('Error in connection'.mysqli_error());
        }else {
            mysqli_select_db($con,'ymp');

            $query = mysqli_query($con, "select * from mentor where email = '".$b."'");
            if (!$query) {
                die ("Failed to query database" . mysqli_error($con));
            }
            if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0) {
                echo "<div ><h3>Email has already been used</h3><br/>Click <a href='mentorsignup.php'>here</a> to try again</div>";
            }else{
                $sql = ("INSERT INTO mentor VALUES(DEFAULT,'$a','$b','$c','$d','$e')");
                $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

                // insertion to logged category table
                $fs = explode(', ', $fimp);
                foreach ($fs as $f ){
                    mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO logged_cat 
                                        (mentorID, catID) 
                                VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), '$f')");
                }
                $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

                if(!mysqli_query($con, $sql)){
                    die('Could not register'.mysqli_error($con));
                }else{
                    echo "<div class='form'><center><h3>You have successfully registered!</h3><br/>Click here to <a href='loginmentor.php'>login</a></center></div>";
                }
            }
        }
    }else {
        echo "<div class='form'><center><h3>Invalid email address</h3><br/>Click <a href='mentorsignup.php'>here</a> to try again</center></div>";
    }                   
}else{
    echo "<div class='form'><center><h3>Enter values in all fields</h3><br/>Click <a href='mentorsignup.php'>here</a> to try again</center></div>";
}
?>
```

Kindly excuse my inexperience, i'm a newbie. Thank you in advance

Comment: What are you imploding and re-exploding? Have you tried `foreach ($_POST['catID'] as $f )` ?

Comment: @ChibuezeOpata i'm imploding the catID since the mentors can click on as many as they want. Okay i will try that

Comment: Unrelated but it's worth noting you are most likely currently vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks by placing values from $_POST directly into your INSERT query. https://phpdelusions.net/sql_injection

Comment: i think it has something to do with the INT values from the checkbox values being $_POST into the database. I specified the value of catID as INT in the database. Is there a different $_POST hence different implode code for that? Someone please help me

Comment: What do you mean by 'help'. What's the problem now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick.

```
..............

    $f = implode(', ', $_POST['catID']);

    if($a && $b && $c && $d && $e && $f)






..........

    mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO mentor VALUES(DEFAULT,'$a','$b','$c','$d','$e')");
          
    $mentorID = mysqli_insert_id($con);
    $fs = explode(', ', $f);     
    foreach ($fs as $f )
    {
    mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO logged_cat (mentorID, catID) VALUES ('$mentorID', $f)");
    }
```